# Vertically aligning a DIV redux

Tags: html, css

Okay, so this question [has been asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div) many times, yet I still can't produce a working solution.

I'd like to vertically align to the middle arbitrary elements in a DIV.  So, the linked-to tutorial in the above question says:

> ```
> Specify the parent container as position:relative or position:absolute.
> Specify a fixed height on the child container.
> Set position:absolute and top:50% on the child container to move the top down to the middle of the parent.
> Set margin-top:-yy where yy is half the height of the child container to offset the item up.
> ```
>
> An example of this in code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myoutercontainer { position:relative }
    #myinnercontainer { position:absolute; top:50%; height:10em; margin-top:-5em }
</style>
...
<div id="myoutercontainer">
    <div id="myinnercontainer">
        <p>Hey look! I'm vertically centered!</p>
        <p>How sweet is this?!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Except contrary to what the screenshot on the tutorial shows, [this doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/HPN8e/1/).  The only thing I changed was to add a border around the outer DIV, so you can see the vertical alignment.

All this does is produce a zero-height DIV which renders like a straight line.  If you add a height to the outer DIV, you can see the inner content, but it doesn't actually vertically align the content.  So, why doesn't this example work?

Comment: Hey, I successfully centered the inner div, but it's late here, too lazy to think how to center the text. http://jsfiddle.net/HPN8e/2/

Answer (score 0):

I believe your containing div also has to have a specified height. If you inspect the #myoutercontainer div with firebug you see that it actually has a height of 13em, which they don't show in the example code given.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/TLzDv/2/) a different approach based of this [Chris Coyer article](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/). If you want to vertically center the text to a fixed size div, then you can just repeat the process [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/TLzDv/1/). If you want it to align to the right, just turn modify the "text-align: center;" style for myoutercontainer.